# Override event in jQuery assigned in MooTools

Tags: jquery, mootools, mootools-events

One of the site components loads script with this.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){ 
    $$('.kqreply').each(function(el){
        el.addEvent('click', function(e){
            e.stop();
            // SOMETHING ELSE.
    });
});
```

It is loaded in external JS file. After that I load declaration in the head.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $$('.kqreply').each(function(el){
            el.removeEvent('click');
        });

        jQuery('.kqreply').unbind('click');

        jQuery('.kqreply').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

But event defined in first code is triggered anyway. How to that I can override event and run different code?

Comment: Do you have any console error?

Comment: None! And if I add `console.log()` I can confirm that my second code rons after first. But when I clic, first click is executed and then click that was defined by me.

Comment: You can see it  line number 4 `el.removeEvent('click');`. But I cannot set second parameter because in the other file there is anonymous function.

Comment: Sergey, did you solve your problem? (did you notice the word removeEvents() has to be in __plural__?)

Comment: No I did not solve. `removeEvents` does not work either.

Comment: Do you have a live link?

Answer (score 0):

so this is the api:
https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Element/Element.Event.js#L83-L101

mootools allows you to remove events you don't own, which is not a great design decision and is currently being changed for prime - but works well in your favour here.

use either

```
$$('.kqreply').removeEvents('click'); 
// or all mootools events...
$$('.kqreply').removeEvents();`
```

you can get to individual functions you don't own via element storage.

`el.retrieve('events')['keys']['click']` will be an array of all bound fn to the click event.

Comment: You can see in my code example that I have this. But it does not remove.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov you have `el.removeEvent('click');` - this is `el.removeEvents('click')` - PLURAL. the single form expects you to pass it the fn as argument. i've even posted you the link to the source code.